# Excel: Default Date Formatting in Workbooks

Tags: microsoft-excel, localization

This is driving me potty!  To be clear, this is not a UK vs US date format question.

Whenever I enter a date in a workbook, either a new one or an existing one, I will type it in either:
17/02/2020
or
17/02

If I use example A, it will remain formatted as DD/MM/YYYY

If I use example B, it will display as 17-Feb

I am now used to just right clicking the cells or column, Format Cells, and setting the Date format.  But I don't think I should have to.  What I would like to do, is set the default behaviour to always show dates as DD/MM/YYYY unless I've specified specific display criteria.

I've read some answers which suggest that I simply open a blank workbook, set all cells as formatted as dates, and then save this as the template with which I open new workbooks.  If I am understanding this correctly, this will not solve the problem because:

a. It won't deal with my existing workbooks, and opening new sheets on said workbooks.

b. It would have set date formatting as default on all cells, so if I was intending to enter numbers to be displayed as numbers, they would show as a date.

It's not a region / language issue as far as I can see.  Anyone know any way to solve this behaviour?

Thanks in advance.

Using: Excel via Office 365 subscription.  Version 2001 Build 12430.20184
OS: Windows 10 Pro 10.0.18362

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it appears there is a new choice when formatting dates in the format cells menu. Select Gregorian (English) under calendar type.

While copy and pasting dates it would paste 17-Feb, and even would even show that format in the cell preview.  After changing the calendar type it all works correctly.

I hope it saves this choice as the default. If it does not I will do more research.